# \textbackslash shows error "undefined control sequence"

Tags: errors

I am typing the equation with \textbackslash inside as follows. It displays error "underfined control sequence". Can anyone explain me what the problem is? Thanks.

```
Here $x\in [0,\infty]^n$ \textblackslash  $\{1\}$. I got error "Undefined control sequence.

Here a \textbackslash b. This line is OK.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have

\textblackslash

"black" should be "back".  A simple typo.

Comment: oh, why i didn't recognize it. The error message of latex doesn't give me any hint. Thanks a lot friend!